Making Record Count Cumulative Across Monthly Grouping In Report
I have a report for custom object, Tasks.
There's a column for the task name and then I've grouped the forecasted date for each task by row and by month.
Example:



Task Name
Forecast Date
January 2024
February 2024
March 2024




Task 1
Record Count
10
15
12



How can I make these counts cumulative so that Jan is 10, Feb is 25, and March is 37?
